# Upload a csv file to GCP storage , 413 http code error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded a file about 1 GB, but a 413 time out error occurred. How can I solve it?

My code:

```js
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: 'some.json'
})
const bucket = storage.bucket("some");
const blob = bucket.file('upload/' + files[f].originalname)
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream().on('finish', function() {
  console.log('[upload] finished')
});
blobStream.end(files[f].buffer)
```

Comment: Can you show the error log please?

Comment: The log could not be checked. When I send a request, the http status value is pending, and if I wait a little longer, I get a 413 error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typically problem with a large file, you need to use the [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads) feature of google api.

Or you can use the [streaming transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-upload-object-nodejs)

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function streamFileDownload() {
  // The example below demonstrates how we can reference a remote file, then
  // pipe its contents to a local file.
  // Once the stream is created, the data can be piped anywhere (process, sdout, etc)
  await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(fileName)
    .createReadStream() //stream is created
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destFileName))
    .on('finish', () => {
      // The file download is complete
    });

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
  );
}

streamFileDownload().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I trying ..  not working ... just respond pending ㅠㅠ